# Create second GitHub account to choose name of gh-pages blog

Tags: github-pages, account

I have a small personal blog created for free on wordpress.com. I'd like to convert it into static blog (powered by [pelican](https://blog.getpelican.com/)) and move it to GitHub pages.

The wordpress blog already has a name, which I'd like to save. Unfortunately, my personal account's name is completely unrelated to the name of the blog. So I cannot achieve what I want due to fixed naming scheme `{username}.github.io`.

I wonder: **is it OK for me to create second GitHub account for the only purpose of hosting my gh-pages blog on it**? Or it goes against GitHub rules?

P.S. I know that it is possible to buy and use a custom domain outside of GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend migrating to GitHub and then using Netlify's free hosting plan. It's easy to host your GitHub repo. on Netlify. Once you've done that, you can change the `Site Name` property in the Netlify settings. Then your new URL would be `https://{your-blog-name}.netlify.com` assuming it wasn't taken.

As to your question, here are the relevant Terms of Service from GitHub:

> Your login may only be used by one person — i.e., a single login may not be shared by multiple people. A paid organization account may create separate logins for as many users as its subscription allows.
>
> Overall, the number of Users must not exceed the number of accounts you've ordered from us.

- https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/#2-account-requirements

It looks like it isn't against their terms. Tons of people do it and I don't think they really care.

I recommend against making multiple GitHub accounts because it makes things confusing especially when differentiating between which account you're using to develop locally.